# Android app button text disappears after months of working fine

Tags: java, android, oracle, maf

I have a field service reporting android app that I created in Oracle MAF. it has been in use for almost a year now with no UI issues, Over the last few days, I have been getting reports from our end users that the button text is disappearing. so - anywhere where there is a button with text inside it, the text is not visible. same font is being used elsewhere in the app with no issues. All the end users are running this on the Samsung Tab A 8.1. The last android update for the device was a few weeks ago. The problem is slowly propagating, like only 4-5 users a day are reporting that they go to use the app and the text is gone. luckily they are used to the app and know what all the buttons do, but I have to eventually fix it. I can't get any straight answers from Our IT department or Samsung as to why it is happening like this, and the update didn't seem to have anything in it that could do this. A factory reset fixes it for a day or two, and then the issue comes back.

[What it is supposed to look like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OGKQG.png)

[Example of missing text](https://i.stack.imgur.com/leDi5.png)

Like I said, this has been working fine for a while now. I'm mainly looking to see if anyone is aware of an Android update that would cause this, or if there was anything in the Samsung security update that would do it.

Comment: Please, consider posting your code, just a description of your problem is not even near to enough for other users to elaborate an answer to your question, i recommend reading this guide about asking good questions on StackOverflow: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: We can't give you a clear answer based on the history of the app alone. We need to know issue/error behind it. Posting an example might help.

Answer (score 0):

Google pushed an update to Chrome that they have discovered caused problems like this, and many others.

I was able to instruct my end users to disable chrome and let it roll back to the factory version.

this fixed the issue.